# Draw path on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have used below code for draw route, but there is a problem, it can't calculate perfect route.

I used google api which is in `getMapsApiDirectionsUrl()` method. And I used `ReadTask` for get response from api. But it is not working properly for me.

It start route far from marker location & also end far from end location. **Check screen shots**.

> Check in screen shot it shows marker in one place & route start far
>   from some distance.

-If two locations are close to each other then it can't draw route
 - in between them, it draw apart from both location.

Please help me.  Thanks in advance.

This is for calling google api:

```
String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
downloadTask.execute(url);
```

Google API:

```
private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
        String waypoints = "origin="
                + lat + "," + Long
                + "&destination=" + Double.parseDouble(Constants.LATITUDE) + ","
                + Double.parseDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE);

        String sensor = "sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        String params = waypoints + "&" + sensor;
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + params;
        return url;
}
```

This is AsyncTask:

```
private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                String data = "";
                try {
                    HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
                    data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                new ParserTask().execute(result);
            }
        }

        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>
        {
            @Override
            protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData)
            {
                JSONObject jObject;
                List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

                try {
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                    PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
                    routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return routes;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes)
            {
                ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
                PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

                // traversing through routes
                for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                    polyLineOptions.width(3);
                    polyLineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                }

                googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);

            }
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4tTc.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/urXlw.jpg

Comment: I can't understand why are you down vote it. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Anyone have answer of this question. What I have to do?